# Consultar 2 tabelas em um banco sql e mostrar valores repetidos

Tags: sql, select, where

Tenho 2 tabelas em meu banco de dados, uma chamada `pessoas` e outra chamada `resultado`, estou preenchendo a tabela resultado com os sorteios efetuados pela mega sena, a tabela resultado tem os campos:

```
data, dez1, dez2, dez3, dez4, dez5, dez6
```

Já a tabela pessoas tem os campos:

```
nome, dez1, dez1, dez3, dez4, dez5, dez6
```

Gostaria de fazer uma select onde me mostre exatamente quais bolas a pessoas acertou, no caso mostrar as dezenas que são iguais nas duas tabelas, elas não possuem chave estrangeira.

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer talvez não a melhor mas no entanto é possível seria fazeres o seguinte:

```
SELECT `pessoas`.`name`, `pessoas`.`dez1` FROM resultado
INNER JOIN pessoas ON `resultado`.`dez1`=`pessoas`.`dez1`
```

Isto retorna todos os registos da tabela `pessoas` com valores iguais ao `dez1` da tabela `resultado`. Para obter os restantes resultados basta para isso alterar o valor 1 por 2, 3, 4, 5 e 6.

> Exemplo real no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c040d9/20).

**EDIT1**

Consegui melhorar a query, exemplo:

```
SELECT pessoas.name, pessoas.dez1 FROM pessoas
WHERE dez1 IN (SELECT dez1 FROM resultado WHERE data=140317)
OR dez1 IN (SELECT dez2 FROM resultado WHERE data=140317)
OR dez1 IN (SELECT dez3 FROM resultado WHERE data=140317)
OR dez1 IN (SELECT dez4 FROM resultado WHERE data=140317)
OR dez1 IN (SELECT dez5 FROM resultado WHERE data=140317)
OR dez1 IN (SELECT dez6 FROM resultado WHERE data=140317);
```

Nesta query fazemos um select ao primeiro valor de todas as pessoas, e depois vamos comparar se é igual a algum dos 6 do resultado. Inclui ainda a condição para saber ir procurar ao dia certo.

> Exemplo real no [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/145f8b/9).

Comment: no caso se eu quiser comparar a dez1 de pessoas as 6 dezenas do resultado, eu tenho que repetir esses 6 passos nas 6 dezenas ne isso

Comment: @RenanCarvalho fiz um update há resposta, com a sua dúvida, espero ter conseguido ajudar

Comment: muito obrigado meu amigo, infelizmente não soluciona o meu caso, mas agradeço desde já sua ajuda, acho que esta me faltando conhecimento, vou da uma estudada melhor em outra forma de conseguir isso, já tentei em java e php mas nada, eu quero fazer 2 tabelas onde uma tivessem os resultado da mega e a outra as apostas das pessoas, em todo resultado da mega sena o programa verificaria nas apostas das pessoas e marcaria quantas bolas cada pessoa acertou e errou, se vc conhecer algo que eu possa estudar para conseguir fazer isso agradeço mais uma vez

Comment: @RenanCarvalho a minha solução funciona com php, java, ou com qualquer outra língua apesar de não ser a mais correta, precisa é de criar uma rotina dentro de um while, algo do género: 1ºusa "while i < 6 do chamarotina(i); i = i+1"; 2ºna rotina faz a query e guarda os valores em uma lista. Tente algo desse género, alguma coisa dúvida ou explicação um pouco mais detalhada avise.